# How to network boot one computer(no OS) from another (Windows 7) and install Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, boot, networking

I have a pretty old laptop, which does not have option to boot from USB devices and it's Optical Drive does not work. But it has support for network booting (PXE).
Can you tell me what tool/procedure I need to configure my other machine to act as a network boot server, on which I load the Ubuntu Setup files from the disk.

Any help is much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Set up an ubuntu VM on the windows box with bridged networking.  Then on this box set up an installation server like so: http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_pxe_install_server

Comment: it is an oldish tutorial so some of the package name may have changed